# How to investigate the uniform convergence of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

> Given this series: 
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(1+x^2)^n}, $$
>   for which values of $x$ is it uniformly convergent?

Determining the points for which it is point-wise convergent is very easy, by just using the root test, I came up with a result that the series is point-wise convergent for all $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

However, I have no idea on how to get the values of $x$ for which this series is uniformly convergent. Am I supposed to use the definition for uniform convergence or the Weierstrass M test?

Comment: It should be uniformly convergent on any subset away from $0$, i.e. $|x| > \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Uniform convergence only makes sense on sets of points, not at individual values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The series is uniformly convergent in any **subset** of $I_a:=(-\infty,-a]\cup [a,+\infty)$ with $a>0$. For $x\in I_a$,
$$0<\frac{1}{n(1+x^2)^n}\leq \frac{1}{n(1+a^2)^n}$$
and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(1+a^2)^n}$ is a convergent series (use the ratio test). Then uniform  convergence follows from the [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test).

However, the series is not uniformly convergent in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. For $x\not=0$, let $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(1+x^2)^n}$.
Then
$$\begin{align}
\sup_{x\not=0}\left|f(x)-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n(1+x^2)^n}\right|
&=\sup_{x\not=0}\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(1+x^2)^n}\\
&\geq \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(1+1/n)^n} \quad\text{($x=1/\sqrt{n}$)}\\
&\geq  \frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}=+\infty
\end{align}$$
where at the last line we applied $(1+1/n)^n\leq 3$ (or we may note that  $(1+1/n)^n\to e$).

Comment: the inequality in the last line is incorrect. $n>N ~\Rightarrow \frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{N}$ and $\frac{1}{(1+1/N)^n}<\frac{1}{(1+1/N)^N}$

Comment: Also, your second last line, it should be $x=1/\sqrt{n}$

Comment: @MathFail Thanks s lot! At some point I swapped $N$ and $n$.

Comment: No worries, you are welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Take $a>0$. Then$$|x|\geqslant a\implies\frac1{1+x^2}\leqslant\frac1{1+a^2}\implies(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):\frac1{n(1+x^2)^n}\leqslant\frac1{n(1+a^2)^n}$$and therefore the series converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}\setminus(a,a)$, by the Weierstrass $M$-test.